# Two issues with battery report

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, battery-life, hp

The first issue is the design capacity. Ever since I got the laptop a bit over a year ago, it has read exactly the same as the full charge capacity, even though they both started off at around 42000 mWh.

[image]

The other thing is the battery life estimate. Every now and then, it comes up with some enormous number, the latest being 142801 hours.

Are these possibly linked to HP PC Hardware Diagnostics Windows or other HP apps, or is it purely a Windows problem? Either way, are there any fixes?

Comment: Use the HP Update App to update all Power Drivers and BIOS (UEFI).  Do a final restart and test.

Comment: "Design capacity" is an attribute of your battery, saved and reported by the battery itself.

Comment: "Full charge capacity" is the amount of energy the battery can store when the state of charge is 100%, so after a year it should be somewhat lower than the Design capacity. Try to do [battery calibration](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/how-to-calibrate-laptop-battery.html).

Comment: @John I tried the Software and Drivers page on the HP website, and the auto detect said no drivers were needed. I then downloaded HP Support Assistant (which I think must have replaced HP Update, as I can't find it), and it only came up with two Realtek drivers.

Comment: Perhaps contact HP Support.  I have Lenovo thinkpads and the battery app is accurate

Comment: Well this is interesting: the HP Support Assistant comes with a battery health check, and it comes up with the correct design capacity, saying 43WHr, and the full charge capacity at 38WHr. So it appears to be a Windows problem.